# Ending a "While" loop python?

Tags: python

This might be a really dumb question, but I can't see why this loop doesn't end. I'm aware that `while True` is an infinite loop, but I'm pretty sure there are also ways to get out of them. Does anyone know how to end this code, so that if they enter "yes" etc. it continues on through the program but if they enter "no" etc. or anything else it asks them for their name again

```
while True:
  user_name = input("What do you want your name to be? (Suggest using Forename and Surname!")
  user_name_check = input("Your name is " + user_name + "? Is this correct?")

  if user_name_check == "yes" or "Yes" or "y" or "Y":
    break
  elif user_name_check == "no" or "No" or "n" or "N":
    pass
  else:
    print("Sorry, please only enter yes or no. Re-enter your name and try again.")
    pass
```

Comment: `or` doesn't work that way. See the duplicate.

Comment: `if user_name_check.lower().startswith("y")`

Comment: the if statements are always True because you check if the string "Yes" evaluates to true. Try user_name_check in ("yes", "YES", "y")

Comment: I dont think the if statement works the way you think it is expected to. You need to check for each condition. Instead why dont you do `if user_name_check in ["yes","Yes","y", "Y"]:`

Comment: btw, your final `pass` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if user_name_check == "yes" or user_name_check == "Yes" or user_name_check == "y" or user_name_check == "Y":
```

Comment: and dito for the second condition

Comment: yes, do the same for all

Comment: thanks for the help : )